# GhostDriver doesn't quit after Selenium test run

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, phantomjs, ghostdriver

In my first very simple test of Selenium with GhostDriver (PhantomJS) the tests pass, but PhantomJS.exe doesn't exit. I'm running on Windows 7, PhantomJS 1.9.0, Selenium WebDriver API 2.32.1 and NUnit 2.6.2.12296, .NET 3.5.

Here's my C#/Nunit/WebDriver code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Driver
{
    IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(@"D:\src\Tests\Drivers");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        driver.Quit();
        driver.Dispose();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GoogleSearch()
    {
        //Navigate to the site
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        Assert.AreEqual("Google", driver.Title);
    }
}
```

And here's everything from PhantomJS:

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2013-04-26T16:38:56.417Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 64183
[INFO  - 2013-04-26T16:38:56.630Z] Session [c9f2b8e0-ae8f-11e2-a7c1-159b6700bc86
] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"",
"platform":"ANY"}
[INFO  - 2013-04-26T16:38:56.649Z] Session [c9f2b8e0-ae8f-11e2-a7c1-159b6700bc86
] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":
"1.9.0","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.3","platform":"windows-7
-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"d
atabaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":f
alse,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnab
led":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":
{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2013-04-26T16:38:56.701Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionComman
d - New Session Created: c9f2b8e0-ae8f-11e2-a7c1-159b6700bc86
[INFO  - 2013-04-26T16:38:59.470Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
```

But it never does shutdown... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce this, using the exact same environment. (Run the test through `nunit.exe` )

> Windows 7, PhantomJS 1.9.0, Selenium WebDriver API 2.32.1 and NUnit
>   2.6.2.12296, .NET 3.5.

As Selenium and PhantomJS have both upgraded to newer versions. I'd suggest you to upgrade yours as well, and see if this issue appears again.

[Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list): [selenium-dotnet-2.33.0.zip](https://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-dotnet-2.33.0.zip)

[PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html): [phantomjs-1.9.1-windows.zip](https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.1-windows.zip)

Also a side note, I don't think you need call both `Quit()` and `Dispose()`, as from the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs), this is how `Quit()` method is implemented.

```
/// <summary>
/// Close the Browser and Dispose of WebDriver
/// </summary>
public void Quit()
{
   this.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe it's been fixed, then ... I was just being extra-cautious with the quit/dispose - because the issue was in that area.

Comment: Clearly nothing happening with this. Will just accept an answer as I'm now unable to retest.

Answer (score 1):

```
[TestFixture]
public class Driver
{
    [Start]
    public void Start()
    {
       using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(@"D:\src\Tests\Drivers"))
       {
          driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";
          Assert.AreEqual("Google", driver.Title);
       }
    }
}
```

This will fix your problem, just always remember to encapsulate things in using statements when you can or explicitly Call `driver.Dispose();` if it's a public variable, you can put Dispose in the deconstructor of the class or something a long those lines if you wanted, when the class is exited the deconstructor will be called and do your lines of code.

Using statements will take care of the cleanup for you.